# How to find outer control from nested inner control

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have the following nested structure.  What I need is to filter a DB Linq query from within CustomControl1 code behind based on the value of the RadioButtonList selection.

```
x MainPage1 
x---- Panel1 (modal popup)
x--------- UpdatePanel (upMailOrStatusAction, on Panel1)
x-------------- RadioButtonList (rblActionLevel, on UpdatePanel)
x-------------- SubForm1 (on Panel1)
x------------------- CustomControl1 (on Subform1)
x------------------------ DropDownList (on CustomControl1)
```

I am trying something like the following to find the control, but it says "The name 'upMailOrStatusAction' does not exist in the current context.

```
RadioButtonList rbl = upMailOrStatusAction.FindControl("rblActionLevel") as RadioButtonList;
```

What is the best way to find the RadioButtonList control?  Yes, I am fairly new with this!

Thank you,
Jim in Suwanee, GA

Ok, Here is the Popup aspx:

```
            <asp:Panel ID="pnlAddMailOrStatusAction" runat="server" CssClass="modalPopupLarge" Style="display: none;">
            <asp:UpdatePanel ID="upMailOrStatusAction" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional" ChildrenAsTriggers="false" RenderMode="Block">
                <Triggers>
                    <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="rblActionType" />
                </Triggers>
                <ContentTemplate> 
                    <div class="borderDiv"> 
                        <table class="borderTable0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                            <thead>
                                <tr align="left">
                                    <th colspan="9">Action Detail</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="1">
                                        <label class="labelfield">Action Level:</label>
                                    </td>
                                    <td colspan="1" rowspan="1" align="left">
                                        <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblActionLevel" runat="server" AutoPostBack="True" RepeatDirection="Horizontal"
                                            RepeatLayout="Flow">
                                            <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Value="Base" Text="Base&nbsp;&nbsp;" />
                                            <asp:ListItem Value="Coverage" Text="Coverage" />
                                        </asp:RadioButtonList>
                                    </td>
                                    <td colspan="1" align="left">
                                        <asp:Label ID="lblMSCoverage" runat="server" class="labelfield" Text="Coverage:" />
                                    </td>
                                    <td colspan="1" align="left">
                                        <asp:Label ID="txtMSCoverage" runat="server" />
                                    </td>
                                    <td colspan="5">
                                        &nbsp;
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="9">
                                        <hr />
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                   <td colspan="9">
                                    <st:MailAddSubform runat="server" ID="mailAddSubform" />
                                    <st:StatusActionAddSubform runat="server" ID="statusActionAddSubform" Visible="false" />
                                   </td>
                                </tr>
                                <tr>
                                    <td colspan="9">
                                        <hr />
                                    </td>
                                </tr> 
                            </tbody>    
                        </table>
                    </div>
                </ContentTemplate>
            </asp:UpdatePanel>
         </asp:Panel>
```

And here is the subform aspx:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="MailAddSubform.ascx.cs" 
Inherits="Company.Solutions.Web.Controls.MailAddSubform" %>
```

Action:
        
        
            
        
    
    
        
        
            Message:    
        
        
            
        
    



And here is the custom control aspx:

     



    
      
        
            
            
            
        
        
             
        
      


    

    
        
            Filters

And finally, here is the code behind for the custom control.  Look for StackOverflow for where I am tring to lookup the radio button list:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;
using Company.Solutions.Data;
using Company.Solutions.Data.Model;
using Company.Solutions.Business.ViewModels;
using Company.Solutions.Business.Helpers;


namespace Comapny.Solutions.Web.Controls
{
    public partial class StMailActionLookup : System.Web.UI.UserControl
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           BindForm();
        }

        protected void BindForm()
        {
            IEnumerable actions = GetClaimMailActions(GetFilter());
            ddlLookup.DataSource = actions;
            ddlLookup.DataTextField = "CodeAndDescription";
            ddlLookup.DataValueField = "actionCd";
            ddlLookup.DataBind();
        }

        //protected void ddlLookup_DataBound1(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        //{
        //    ddlLookup.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("<Please Choose an Action>", String.Empty));
        //} 

        private MailActionFilters GetFilter()
        {
            MailActionFilters filters = new MailActionFilters();
            if (chkForms.Checked)
                    filters |= MailActionFilters.Forms;
            if (chkRequested.Checked)
                    filters |= MailActionFilters.RequestedInfo;
            if (chkOther.Checked)
                    filters |= MailActionFilters.Other;

            return filters;
        }

        public IEnumerable GetClaimMailActions(MailActionFilters filter)
        {
            RelationalDataContext db = RelationalDataContext.Create();
            List<Expression<Func<ClaimMailAction, bool>>> predicates = new List<Expression<Func<ClaimMailAction, bool>>>();

            const string MAIL_ACTIONS = "0";
            const char FORMS = 'F';
            const char REQUESTED_INFO = 'R';
            const char EXCLUDE = 'X';



            //StackOverflow help

            //RadioButtonList rbl = (RadioButtonList) Control.Parent.FindControl("rblActionLevel");




            if ((!chkForms.Checked && !chkRequested.Checked && !chkOther.Checked) | (chkForms.Checked && chkRequested.Checked && chkOther.Checked))
            {
                predicates.Add(cma => cma.ActionCd.StartsWith(MAIL_ACTIONS) && (cma.EsolutionsCode == null || cma.EsolutionsCode!= EXCLUDE));
            } else {

                if((filter & MailActionFilters.Forms) == MailActionFilters.Forms)
                    predicates.Add(cma => cma.ActionCd.StartsWith(MAIL_ACTIONS) && cma.EsolutionsCode == FORMS);

                if((filter & MailActionFilters.RequestedInfo) == MailActionFilters.RequestedInfo)
                    predicates.Add(cma => cma.ActionCd.StartsWith(MAIL_ACTIONS) && cma.EsolutionsCode == REQUESTED_INFO);

                if((filter & MailActionFilters.Other) == MailActionFilters.Other)
                    predicates.Add(cma => cma.ActionCd.StartsWith(MAIL_ACTIONS) && (cma.EsolutionsCode == null || (cma.EsolutionsCode != EXCLUDE && cma.EsolutionsCode != FORMS && cma.EsolutionsCode != REQUESTED_INFO)));
            }

            var predicate = PredicateBuilder.Make<ClaimMailAction>();
            predicates.ForEach(delegate(Expression<Func<ClaimMailAction, bool>> expr)
            {
                predicate = predicate.Or(expr);
            });

            var qry = db.ClaimMailActions.Where(predicate).Select(c => new { c.ActionCd, CodeAndDescription = string.Format("{0} - {1}", c.ActionCd, c.ActionDesc) });

            return qry.ToList();
        }
    }
}
```

New code list. My co-worker used this for another lookup.  Could someone show me how I would do something similar for this lookup?  Even if inefficient, if it works so be it.

```
HtmlForm form;



        foreach(var ctl in Page.Controls[0].Controls)

        {

            if(ctl is HtmlForm)

            {

                form = ctl as HtmlForm;

                ContentPlaceHolder holder = form.FindControl("DefaultContent") as ContentPlaceHolder;

                if (holder != null)

                {

                   PlaceHolder paymentControlHolder = holder.FindControl("plcPaymentForm") as PlaceHolder;

                    if (paymentControlHolder != null)

                    {

                        IListener listener;

                        foreach (var c in paymentControlHolder.Controls)

                        {

                            if (c is IListener)

                            {

                                listener = c as IListener;

                                rblPaymentType.SelectedIndexChanged += listener.AddHandler();

                            }

                        }

                    }

                }





            }

        }
```

Ok, I am trying this, but have not quite figured out yet how to determine the selected value of the radio button:

```
HtmlForm form;
        foreach (var ctl in Page.Controls[0].Controls) { 
            if (ctl is HtmlForm) { 
                form = ctl as HtmlForm; 
                ContentPlaceHolder holder = form.FindControl("DefaultContent") as ContentPlaceHolder; 
                if (holder != null) {
                    RadioButtonList rblControlHolder = holder.FindControl("rblActionLevel") as RadioButtonList; 
                    if (rblControlHolder != null) { 

                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure whether I fully understood what you're trying to achieve. But if you want to find a control on your page, you might want a solution as I posted [here](http://blog.js-development.com/2008/06/recursive-version-of-findcontrol-method.html).

```
 public static Control FindControlRecursive(Control parent, string controlId)
 {
     if (controlId == parent.ID)
         return parent;

     foreach (Control ctrl in parent.Controls)
     {
         Control tmp = FindControlRecursive(ctrl, controlId);
         if (tmp != null)
             return tmp;
     }

     return null;
 }
```

It is a recursive implementation of the standard find control. But choose your parent wisely. If you have a large page and you indicate that to be the search root, then it will traverse all of the controls of the page till the deepest nested control. You could also go the reversed way, basically starting from your control and recursively go up till you reach the page level. Would be another option.

The only issue I found with this recursive find is that you might get problems when having a repeater on your page. You shouldn't traverse the repeater's inner controls. Due to its architecture there are some problems that it will loose it's viewstate otherwise. Once I've time I'll post an update of this recursive method.

**Edit:** 
You get the selected entry of the radio button as follows:

```
RadioButtonList myInstance = //find my radio button list
string selectedValue = myInstance.SelectedValue;
```

Comment: Juri,
The goal is simply to determine the radio button value so I can modify my query to fill a drop down list accordingly.  I will try your lookup as well as it may come in handy.  
Thanks!

Jim

Comment: well if your radiobuttonlist is on your user control or page you should have direct access to it, don't you? Or at least to it's container element. I don't really get why you have to traverse everything from your page downwards.

Comment: Btw, the code below could be solved by calling my FindControlRecursive(this.Page, "rblActionLevel") as RadioButtonList, although I'm still convinced there's much a simple way.

Comment: Nope, I do not have direct access, I am going to try your method, that looks pretty cool!

Thanks,
Jim

Comment: Ok, now I got your problem. Well in this specific case my FindControlRecursive may work fine, but remember usually there is a better way for achieving these kind of things. The dependencies you have from your inner subcontrol to the radiobuttonlist may pose a problem if you reuse your subcontrol in another context where there might not be any such radiobuttonlist. Optimally you should resolve this dependency somehow more explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Use the property Parent to make your way up the control tree.

```
CustomControl1.Parent.Parent.Parent.FindControl("rblActionLevel");
```

Comment: Ok guys, I get the idea but I am in the code behind of the custom control which is defined as this:
public partial class StMailActionLookup : System.Web.UI.UserControl

And I get "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Web.UI.Control.Parent.Get'

Using the following:
RadioButtonList rbl = (RadioButtonList) StMailActionLookup.Parent.FindControl("rblActionLevel");

Comment: This is how the custom control is defined from within the subform:

<div>
    <st:MailActionLookup ID="mailActionLookup" runat="server" />
        </div>

Comment: Why don't you post your whole form so we can analyze the structure.

Answer (score 0):

Piggybacking on Chaos...

```
RadioButtonList rbl = (RadioButtonList)Control.Parent.FindControl("rblActionLevel")
```

Answer (score 0):

> "An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'System.Web.UI.Control.Parent.Get' Using the following: RadioButtonList rbl = (RadioButtonList) StMailActionLookup.Parent.FindControl("rblActionLevel");

You reference the object type "StMailActionLookup" when you should reference "mailActionLookup", the ID of the instance of the control.

So that code would look like:

```
RadioButtonList rbl = (RadioButtonList) mailActionLookup.Parent.FindControl("rblActionLevel");
```

Not sure if that's the problem with the code you came up with, however, just a small correction.

Also, remember that the UpdatePanel is a templated control and the RadioButtonList and all other controls are rendered inside of its ContentTemplateContainer somewhere in the UpdatePanels's lifecycle (I think it's somewhere around CreateChildControls). It depends on where your BindForm() method is called from, but it could be that the RadioButtonList truly isn't available yet at the time you're trying to find it. Even if its in markup, controls in a template aren't created the same way as other controls in markup are. They're kind of weird beasts.

For a test, try running the find control code in an overridden Render method or something like that. By the Render method you're guaranteed that all controls will be available.

```
public override Render(HtmlTextWriter writer) {
   RadioButtonList rbl = (RadioButtonList)upMailOrStatusAction.FindControl("rblActionLevel");
}
```

Also, since the upMailOrStatusAction is an UpdatePanel, the code might be

```
upMailOrStatusAction.ContentTemplateContainer.FindControl("rblActionLevel");
```

Comment: For both your first code example "mailActionLookup" and the second example "upMailOrStatusAction", i get "the name does not exist in the current context" error with each error referencing the field in quotes here.  I haven't tried the Render just yet but I will.  Thanks,
Jim

Comment: Yes, sorry, I should've read the code more closely. 

The mailActionLookup is a sibling of the RadioButtonList (completely missed that) so writing non-brittle code is tough. Your best bet is to start the Page and do a recursive search down the hierarchy for the radiobuttonlist. Page.FindControl won't do the trick because it only goes one level deep. You'll need to find a helper method on the web. 

Or, you can right a helper method that starts from the mailActionControl and goes up the hierarchy searching the control's collection of each parent control. Both are pretty inefficient though.

Comment: Wonder if I could set a session variable based on the radio button selection and read that value here? There should be an easier way!  Thanks,
Jim

Comment: I entered an example search above (see last code post).  Can someone give me a guess as to the wording of a similar lookup for this?  Thank you,

Jim

Answer (score 0):

Ok, finally got this working thanks to everybody's help.  Thanks JayRu for steering me in the right direction.  Here is what I am using (it still needs a bit of work to hook it up):

```
HtmlForm form;
        foreach (var ctl in Page.Controls[0].Controls) { 
            if (ctl is HtmlForm) { 
                form = ctl as HtmlForm; 
                ContentPlaceHolder holder = form.FindControl("DefaultContent") as ContentPlaceHolder; 
                if (holder != null) {
                    RadioButtonList rblControlHolder = holder.FindControl("rblActionLevel") as RadioButtonList; 
                    if (rblControlHolder != null) {
                        if (rblControlHolder.SelectedValue == "Base") {

                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: If JayRu put you on the path to finding the solution, perhaps you should accept his answer.  Or at least vote him up (assuming you have enough rep to vote ... don't know)