# How to find GridView on Page

Tags: asp.net, gridview, findcontrol

I have nested GridViews on my page (Default) and I need to get the ID of the GridView inside but it's returning null. I have an UpdatePanel outside the nested GridViews. It's using a masterpage.

```
GridView gv = (GridView)UpdatePanel1.FindControl("GridViewSchedule");
```

Comment: are you sure the gridview is at the first level?

Comment: Take a look at this solution: [How to find outer control from nested inner control][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1371290/how-to-find-outer-control-from-nested-inner-control

Answer (score 0):

Here is the helper method to find a control recursively.

```
public static Control FindControlRecursive(Control root, string id)
{
    if (root.ID == id)
        return root;

    return root.Controls.Cast<Control>()
        .Select(c => FindControlRecursive(c, id))
        .FirstOrDefault(c => c != null);
}

// Usage
var gridView = FindControlRecursive(UpdatePanel1, "GridViewSchedule");
```